# 11ty one shorcode call another shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, eleventy

Is it possible for me to write one shortcode, and it would trigger several others?
Let's say I have shorcode using njk:

```
{% card %}
```

inside, let's say the following code:

```
  eleventyConfig.addNunjucksShortcode("card", function() {
    return `
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    `
  });
```

And I have another shortcode:

```
{% img "path-to-img.jpg" %}.
```

It has an img src parameter, and will render to some img.

```
  eleventyConfig.addNunjucksShortcode("img", function(path) {
    return `
    <img src="${path}">
    `
  });
```

I need that when I call the card shortcode, it called the img shortcode and passed the parameter to it.Let's say that I write:

```
{% card 'path-to-img.jpg' %}
```

And it will render at:

```
<div class="card">
  <img src="path-to-img.jpg">
</div
```

Just in case, I need to call one shortcode, paired and nested shortcodes will not suit me:

```
{% column %}
  {% img 'path-to-img.jpg' %}
{% endcolumn %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this way (there is not a img, but the meaning is the same):

```
  eleventyConfig.addNunjucksShortcode("inner", function() {
    return `<div class="inner">`;
  });

  eleventyConfig.addNunjucksShortcode("endinner", function() {
    return `</div>`;
  });

  eleventyConfig.addShortcode("card", function(text) {
    return `<div class="card">
              ${eleventyConfig.nunjucksShortcodes.inner()}
              ${text}
              ${eleventyConfig.nunjucksShortcodes.endinner()}
            </div>`;
   });
```

And call it:

```
{% card "text" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

While not really a 'shortcode calling a shortcode', I'd take the logic of `img` and abstract it into a method. Have the img shortcode call that to handle it's logic, and then `card` call the abstracted out method to get it's HTML result as well. Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I somehow succeeded, posted the answer to the question. Now I'm trying to beat the asynchronous shortcodes.

Comment: Interesting - my concern would be, is calling a shortcode via `eleventyCondfig.nunjucksShoretcodes` documented? I didn't see that.